# Is there a way to have a 2 dimensional vector in my table?

Tags: smart-contract, abi

I can have a string vector by manually changing the type in my abi file to `string[]` but if I try `string[][]` I get an ABI error in my node:

> Error 3015004: The type defined in the ABI is invalid

Any thoughts?

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: Error 3015004: The type defined in the ABI is invalid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I found the answer in developers telegram. If anyone has the same problem you can use:
    `vector<vector<foo>>`
and in the abi file you define a new type foo_vector of type foo[] and then on your table you define it as foo_vector[]